# Solspace Calendar not showing custom field

Tags: solspace-calendar

I've got Solspace Calendar set up and working using the `{exp:calendar:cal}` tag but I can't get a custom field for location to show up. I've even got the `enable='custom_fields'` parameter set. Shows up like this at the moment: http://cl.ly/image/1I2E411L0m0b

Using EE 2.8.1, Calendar 1.8.9. Here's the code: http://pastie.org/9320357

The events channel is the default one that is installed when you install Calendar with a short name of calendar_events.

I've tried changing the custom field short name to something else (like "my_event_location") and that doesn't fix it.

Comment: What type of field is event_location? Have you tested in a standard channel entries loop and just make sure you have the proper syntax for the field?

Comment: Looking at that now. It's a standard Text Input field. It's not showing up properly in the channel entries loop either. Just the EE code for it. Tried the description field (`{event_description}`) in the same manner and that comes up blank (no code or output of any kind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got it working. Uninstalled & reinstalled Calendar to no avail. Turned out to be incorrect DB in my config file.